# Ideal/optimum/best pixel dimensions of video to be viewed on iphone

Tags: iphone, video

I'm exporting MOVs from Flash, then converting them to mp4 with Handbrake. The video will scale to the screen size, but I would prefer it to scale down, rather than scale up. So, what are the maximum/optimum/best pixel width and height of a MOV/mp4 for iphones? Or, to take it a step back in the process, what are the pixel dimensions I should set for my Flash document (which is then exported to MOV at 1:1)? PS: I know iphone screen sizes have changed with each new iphone, and screen sizes come in [points, rendered pixels, physical pixels and physical devices](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions). But hopefully in the end there's max X-px x Y-px. ([I asked this over at Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/whats-the-maximum-necessary-size-in-pixels-for-a-video-for-iphone), but no answers)

Comment: Instead of cross-posting please flag the original post (on Video Production) for mod attention and have one of the mods there migrate it to Ask Different. Then please delete this one here.

Comment: @patrix, OK, have asked. Hopefully, it will appear here as a new question and not dated 26 June.

Comment: It will keep the date AFAIK but show up as a new question anyway

Comment: I think you need to figure out what you are asking before I can migrate it over.  I think part of the problem with the original question is that you are kind of bouncing between "what is the best resolution for the video" and then bouncing to "what is the highest resolution used by any iphone to date".  The former question is on topic for Video Production and doesn't seem likely to be on topic for Ask Different.  The later is not on topic for video production (which is likely why it got no answers) and is certainly on topic for Ask Different.

Comment: [Question on Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/whats-the-best-size-in-pixels-for-a-video-for-iphone)

Comment: I think your best bet is to either alter the Video Production question to be more open ended to how to decide on the best resolution option (which would also benefit from more details about what you are trying to do and why iPhones are your only target), alter this question here to focus just on the maximum pixel dimensions of an iPhone screen, or alter both looking for two different answers to two different questions.

Comment: As pointed out by AJ please fix the question on VP first.

Comment: I fixed the question on VP - "maximum needed to display 1:1 on the highest definition iphone screen." Now where does it go?